# Как разбить строку по символу "обратный слэш" в Python

Tags: python, split

Нужно разбить адрес файла по разделителю \

Такой код:

```py
y = 'C:\Users\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\my_file.xls'
y_list = y.split('\\\\')
```

падает с ошибкой:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Как экранировать знак \, чтобы python понял, что это разделитель, по которому нужно разбить строку?

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-os-path-python/funktsija-split-modulja-os-path/

Comment: тут проблема совсем не с разделением, а с тем, что строка 'C:\Users\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\my_file.xls' не сохраняется в переменную

Comment: Выбирайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167154/how-to-split-a-dos-path-into-its-components-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Используйте r-строки. И у вас слишком много бэкслэшей для разбиения:

```py
y = r'C:\Users\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\my_file.xls'
y_list = y.split('\\')

# ['C:', 'Users', 'Downloads', 'Telegram Desktop', 'my_file.xls']
```

К сожалению, r-строки не всегда помогают, во второй строке кода пришлось таки экранировать бэкслэш из-за того, что когда бэкслэшем кончается строка, то r-строка не помогает.

Comment: во второй строке пришлось экранировать, потому что иначе экранируется закрывающая кавычка. r-строки тут не при чем.

Comment: ну или `y.split(chr(92))`

Comment: @Эникейщик r-строка тут при том, что по идее она должна же помогать с бэкслэшами, избавлять от их экранирования, но в случае, когда бэкслэш в конце строки, это не работает, про это я и пишу

Comment: Спасибо! ваши ответы помогли.  И еще узнала много нового)

Comment: Точно, никогда об этом не задумывался. Тут много на эту тему написано https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash

Answer (score 0):

`y = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Telegram Desktop\\my_file.xls"`

`y_list = y.split('\\')`

`print(y_list)`

Comment: Вы уверены в своем коде?

Comment: к сожалению, в исходном адресе файла ничего изменить не получится, он вводится как есть